# Estou utilzando openGL no android, na hora de emular da erro

Tags: android, opengl

Estou testando um exemplo encontrado na internet e na hora da execução me dá o seguinte erro no **LogCat**

> 03-23 09:43:22.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1036): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread
>   72 03-23 09:43:22.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1036): Process:
>   com.obomprogramador.game.openglbasico2, PID: 1036 03-23 09:43:22.286:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1036): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config
>   chosen 03-23 09:43:22.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1036):    at
>   android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:874)
>   03-23 09:43:22.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1036):   at
>   android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
>   03-23 09:43:22.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1036):   at
>   android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
>   03-23 09:43:22.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1036):   at
>   android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)

alguém saberia me dizer como corrigir tal erro.

Comment: Aparentemente ele da um erro de "No config chosen", verifique se você chamou o `setEGLConfigChooser`. Mais info neste link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLConfigChooser(boolean)

Comment: @PedroHenrique o o setEGLConfigChooser tem que estar na Activity principal?

Comment: Olá, ele tem que ser colocado na inicialização do OpenGL (mais exemplos aqui http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.opengl.GLSurfaceView). Porém estava vendo a documentação e se ele for omitido ele define umas configurações padrões. Me tira uma dúvida você está utilizando um emulador ou um dispositivo real?

Comment: @PedroHenrique eu utilizei dispositivo real e o emulador

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dois fatos importantes:

1. O emulador **não é** totalmente **garantido**. O seu código pode ser
   perfeito, e mesmo assim falhar catastroficamente nele.
2. Entre a versão 2.x
   e a 4.x do Android, certos **comportamentos mudam**. O código que
   funcionava no 2.2/2.3 pode não funcionar do mesmo jeito no 4.4.

Solução:

1. Chamar `setEGLContextClientVersion(2);`
2. Chamar `setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);` usando os valores padrão

Por exemplo:

```
public class GameSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    private GameRenderer renderer;

    public GameSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        renderer = new GameRenderer();//aonde GameRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
        setRenderer(renderer);
    }
}
```

Lembrando que GameRenderer e GameSurfaceView são classes de responsabilidade sua. Não sei qual o nome que você deu para essas classes no seu projeto.